# how to view ER diagram in Access of existing database

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have got an existing database which I have linked to MS Access. I was wondering whether one can view all existing relationships between the tables (ERD). I don't want to create new relationships but just see the existing ones. I have imported the tables from the database but when I click on relationships in Access it asks me to start linking the tables although they should have been linked already since it's an existing database.

Comment: Have you imported or linked? You will not see the relationsships for linked tables. You would need to choose to import relationships for imported tables.

Comment: and how can you import the relationships? From the odbc connection I can only import the tables..

Comment: If you are importing from something other than Access, you may be best of creating your own script.

Comment: yeah..I am importing from mysql server. What do you mean by creating your own script?

Comment: Some VBA to import and build the relationships. Why not just link the tables?